# Autofac: setting up with Web API 2, what am I missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I'm testing out Autofac in an isolated C# solution, I want to inject a test manager into the home controller, it's set up like this:

**A very simple interface**

```
public interface ITestManager
{
    IEnumerable<string> Get();
}
```

**Implemented by**

```
public class TestManager : ITestManager
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ",
            "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
            "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut ",
            "aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in ",
            "voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint ",
            "occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia ",
            "deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        };
    }
}
```

**This will be received by the TestController**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private ITestManager TestManager { get; set; }

    public TestController(ITestManager testManager)
    {
        TestManager = testManager;
    }
}
```

**And the dependency is set up like this**

```
public static class Autofac
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Base set-up
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Register dependencies

        SetUpRegistration(builder);

        // Build registration.
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void SetUpRegistration(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<TestManager>()
            .As<ITestManager>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

**Which is linked from within the global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    IoC.Autofac.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

Running this results in this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.

What am I missing?

Full stack trace:

**Stack Trace**

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AutofacWebApi.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: what is the full stack trace please?

Comment: I've added it to my question.

Comment: that stack does not originate from autofac so it is not 'wired' correctly here. ru using owin ?

Comment: No but it's included in the web api. If setting it up helps you provide meaningful logging, please provide me with information on how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, remove this method "SetUpRegistration" and use the "Register" method to Register your type. Because I'm not sure the ContainerBuilder registering the type which you have passed.

Comment: Where is `HomeController` defined and registered? Since it's the class in the stack trace, we need to see it as well.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's the old stacktrace, should be TestController.

Comment: important you post the most recent stack trace as not-so-subtle  differences may exist

Comment: I've updated the stacktrace with the correct one.

Comment: it looks to me like you are registering api controllers but `TestController` is not one. have you tried `builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())` instead.
Do you have dll references to both `Autofac.Integrations.Mvc` *and* `Autofac.Integrations.WebApi` ?

Comment: Got it! As you mentioned `RegisterControllers` it clicked, my TestController is of type Controller, not `ApiController`! I copied it from HomeController and didn't change it. Had to be something dumb like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, I copied the controller class information from HomeController, which is of type `Controller`, not `ApiController`!

So the correct implementation is this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private ITestManager TestManager { get; set; }

    public TestController(ITestManager testManager)
    {
        TestManager = testManager;
    }

    // GET: api/Test
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return this.TestManager.Get();
    }
}
```

I was using `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())` to register the controllers, but that is specific for API Controllers only, and, since my TestController was of type `Controller` (which is the core MVC controller type) it wasn't wired up correctly.

Should you wish to use (plain old) MVC as well, you should use this:

`builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())`

Kudos to [wal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224410/wal) for pointing me in the right direction.